# Get Color logs in console for log4j without ANSI color sequence

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I want to color the log4j error logs with red.

I have gone through few links advising how to do that but following all the steps what i see on Eclipse or command console is something like `[[31m INFO[m]` and not the color. I guess plugin is required for both Eclipse and command for ANSI.

But I want to know if there is a way out where we do not require ANSI plugins.
Because Java `System.err` logs do come out to console with red color.

Answer (score 1):

All the text sent to Java's `System.err` is red in Eclipse console only because it was printed on process `Standard Error` channel. To display Log4j logs in red in Eclipse console, you shall tell Log4j to also use this Standard Error channel, with such a line in your Log4j configuration file:

```
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.Target=System.err
```

or if your configuration file is an XML configuration file:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    ....
    <param name="target" value="System.err"/>
    ....
</appender>
```

Comment: i checked this option of setting the target to "System.err" but this will make error as RED only in eclipse but not when the same is run in cmd prompt.. Can you please suggest something which works in both?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make both outputs RED at the same time whitout displaying strange characters in Eclipse output (coloring in red in a real shell may display something like `[[31m` in Eclipse). Don't know if it's possible...